# Programmatically execute an action set (Rules module)

Tags: rules

I want to use Rules UI to define some action sets, but want to execute those actions programmatically from a custom module.

How to I execute the action by code and pass the needed arguments (just a node in this case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have set it up as a rules component, you can use [`rules_invoke_component`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_component/7), alternative you can invoke an event, which could trigger mutiple rules by using [`rules_invoke_event`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event/7).

Both is similar in that you pass first a name/id and the rest of the args is passed along, so something like

```
 rules_invoke_component('name', $node);
```

if your custom component rule has several parameters pass them one by one and separate them with comma as example

```
rules_invoke_component('rules_save_search_send_activation_sms',  'paramval1', 'paramval2', ....);
```

is properly how you need to do it. This again depends on how the rule/component is defined and configured.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the function I was looking for. I had to pass the argument directly, though - probably because I just have one arg configured in the component.

`rules_invoke_component('rules_mycomponent', $node);`

Comment: @valderama, great I updated my answer in case others need the same info.

Comment: Does this work for drupal 6?

Comment: @landing Rules have changed a lot from 6 to 7, but `rules_invoke_event` exists in 6 `rules_invoke_component` does not, but I don't believe rules in 6 has the concept of components.

Comment: if you have custom rule compoent ,pass parameters one by one and separate them with comma example `rules_invoke_component('rules_save_search_send_activation_sms',  'test ', '93333333333');`