# How to find out if a Rule is successfully executed or not?

Tags: 7, rules, flags

I am using Drupal7. I have created a custom event for a rule using `hook_rules_event_info()`. I have added a Rules Action for the Rules Event "*Flag a node*".

When I invoke the Rules Event in code, using `rules_invoke_event()`, I have to know whether the Rules Action is executed successfully or not.

How can I identify if the Rules Action fails and handle the failure situation gracefully? Primarily I need to know how to identify whether the rule is successfully executed or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically execute an action set (Rules module)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/programmatically-execute-an-action-set-rules-module)

Comment: @anil This is different.i know how to execute an action set programatically.I need to verify programatically whether the rule is executed successfully or not

Comment: @AnilSagar not duplicate, or not this one anyway. Gobinath, why can't you use debugger or watchdog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try enabling debugging in rules->settings.
Hope this will help you in finding the execution of action
[image]