# How to trigger Rules from Ajax-picture-uploader?

Tags: 7, users, rules

I'm using Rules with event  "After updating an existing user account". It should trigger whenever a user uploads a new profile picture.

Now I've added an ajax uploader for user pictures, the Avatar Uploader module.

The problem is that the ajax uploader doesn't trigger the rule.

How can I fix this?

Is there some code I could add to change this and make it trigger the rule?

Comment: No, the event says after **updating** not uploading. Uploading a new img does not update the account until you hit the save button

Comment: yes i understand. but how can it be achieved using the ajax submit?

Comment: Its been years, but you can trigger a rule programatically. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3741/57